# How can I get the events associated with an element that is inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript

I am using Chrome DevTools and am looking at Event Listeners in the element tab. It works great when the element under consideration is not inside an iframe -- but when it is inside an iframe, things are a bit wonky. How can I remedy this? Thanks in advance

edit: I forgot to mention, it's not my site

Comment: If you use `iframe` then you have to make cross site request for getting any callback

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's not my site

Comment: Then you can't do that

Comment: Depending on your users, everything has different rules if you're writing a Chrome Extension, etc. I don't know about your use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security thing with cross-origin iframes. If you own the domain that is inside of that iframe, then it should work fine. [Working example for same-origin iframes](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp)

(code from that site is pasted below)

```
const iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]; // grab a reference
iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body') // here's the body!
```

If you were to execute the above code on an iframe that had a *different* domain than the page you're currently on, then you would get a CORS error that looks like the below

[image: example of cors error]

A workaround is if you have a script inside the frame and use something like a `postMessage` you can broadcast the information you want into the parent window that's embedding the iframe. This requires working with the company/website whose domain you're embedding, which obviously requires some amount of trust that you won't do anything malicious.

If you think about it, one of the reasons this might exist is so that if you are embedding a login page for another site, you can't add event listeners and steal users' logins.

Hope this helps!